# reading the first line from each file and comparing them to a reference number

Tags: bash

I have three input files. I will read the first line of each the input file and I will compare them to a reference number. All values (a1,a2 and a3) I read from different input files should smaller than my "absolute reference value (aref)". My script gives the error for the reference value: line ..: -2.13: No such file or directory. How can I fix my code? And my if condition is correct?

```
#!/bin/bash -f

a1=$(head -n 1 input1.xvg)
a2=$(head -n 1 input2.xvg)
a3=$(head -n 1 input3.xvg)

aref=-2.13

if [a1 < $aref && a2 < $aref && a3 < $aref] ; then

    echo "It's good"

else 

   echo "It isn't good"

fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as your syntax errors (you need spaces after `[` and before `]` in a test and you're missing some `$` from your variable names), it looks like you're trying to compare floating point numbers, which is not supported by bash. One option would be to use `bc`, inside an arithmetic context instead:

```
if (( $(bc <<<"$a1 < $aref && $a2 > $aref && $a3 > $aref") )); then
    echo "It's good"
else
    echo "It isn't good"
fi
```

The output of the command substitution `$( ... )`, is `1` or `0`, depending on whether the conditions are true or false. The arithmetic context `(( ... ))` returns success if the output is returns 1 and failure if it returns 0.

If you would like to work with the absolute values of your variables, one way to do so would be to use `${a1#-}`, `${aref#-}`, etc. which removes the leading `-` from each variable.

Comment: @erhan the numbers are treated as strings, so it doesn't matter whether they're floats or not. If the number is positive, the expansion doesn't have any effect, so it works either way. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [[ instead of [ in your if statement. Because you're using [ the shell thinks you are passing a file, not comparing to values.

Try to write your if like this

```
if [[ $a1 < $aref && $a2 > $aref && $a3 > $aref ]] ; then
```

To use the absolute value of aref use this:

```
let "aref=$aref<0?-$aref:$aref"
```

Comment: OK. But how can I set "absolute `aref` " in `if` condition? In this way, the code uses minus `aref` value. It woks now.

Comment: Bash doesn't understand floating point numbers, so this approach will not work.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't pay attention to the value of aref.

Comment: Also your explanation is misleading. It is perfectly valid to use the standard `[` for a test - the reason for the error is that there's no space between the `[` and `a1` so the shell is attempting to run a command called `[a1`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Using the [[ ... ]] test construct, rather than [ ... ] can prevent many logic errors in scripts. For example, the &&, ||, <, and > operators work within a [[ ]] test, despite giving an error within a [ ] construct.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not disputing the usefulness of bash's extended tests (although I would say your example is more of a syntax error than a logic error, as none of those operators are supported in simple tests). I'm just saying that _only_ changing `[` to `[[` in the OP's code, as you have suggested in your first sentence, would not have helped, as `[[a1` is a syntax error, just the same as `[a1`. If the OP was working with integers, your code would be correct but your explanation is not.

Comment: I understand :). I gave my response based solely on the error he provided: "-2.13: No such file or directory". I'm guessing he wrote the code correctly in his script, but forgot the space here.